# how to set a foo: symbol to a variable in ruby

Tags: ruby, httparty

I'm using HTTParty and I'm trying to write a query method like this:

```
self.find_stuff(stuff, query_key = 'foo')
   response = HTTParty.get(some_URL,
                           headers: { some headers go here },
                           :content_type => json,
                           query: { query_key: bar }
```

How do I pass `'foo'` into the query_key?

`foo` cannot be a string. I am trying to do `foo: bar` by default if the `query_key` argument is left alone. But I want it flexible enough that I can pass a parameter to `query_key` without changing the parameter to be `query_key` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tweak your call to look like this:

```
..., query: { query_key => bar }
```

You have to use the older hash rocket syntax if your key is not a symbol.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I was looking for. I knew it was something simple. I just couldn't figure it out. As I am new to programming and didn't know what the official term for that was. I kept trying to do #{query_key} but that only works for strings apparently.

Comment: @adbarads That feature (`#{}`) is called "string interpolation" and it only works between double quotes, inside a string.